# Obtain average for unique identifiers in R

Tags: r, dplyr, uniqueidentifier

I have a dataset containing rows of unique identifiers. Each unique identifier occupies several rows b/c each person (identifier) has different ratings. For example unique identifier 1 may have a rating for Goal A, Goal B, Goal C, all represented in a separate row.

What would be the best way to find the average for each unique identifier (i.e. for manager 1 (unique identifier 1), what is their average score across Goal A, Goal B and Goal C?

In excel, I'd do this by using the data sort > and check unique identifiers, copy and paste those values at the bottom of the dataset, and find the average using a series of conditional statements. I'm sure there must be a way to do this in R. Would appreciate any help/insight.

I started with this code, but am not sure if this is what I need. I'm filtering by departments (FSO), then asking it to give me a list of unique IDs, and then computing the average for each manager.

```
df %>% filter(newdept=='FSO') %>%
```

distinct(ID) %>%
  summarize(compmean = mean(CompRating2, na.rm=TRUE))

Comment: You want `group_by(ID)`, not `distinct(ID)`

Comment: So, this: df %>% filter(newdept=='FSO', CompName2=='Lead') %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(compmean = mean(CompRating2, na.rm=TRUE))

Comment: Yep, that's right -- although since you didn't post a sample of data, I can't be sure exactly what you will get.

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution would be to use `aggregate`:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE), score=sample(1:5, 50, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
aggregate(score ~ id, data=dat, mean)
```